# how to parser html with specific div and date using simple dom parser

Tags: php

i want to parser html file by specific date

```
<div class="blog">

<h2 class="date"> 2016 09 08 </h2>
<h3 class ="title"> <a href ="..\>title </a>     

</h3>

</div>
```

i want to get link if date is 2016 09 08
my code

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=blog]    
[plaintext*=2016 09 08]') as $date) {

if(isset($date)){

foreach($html->find('h3[class=title] a[plaintext*=title]') as $a) {

echo substr($urls, 0, strrpos($urls, '/')) . '/' . $a->href ."<br>";

}
}
```

Comment: You have errors? Or what?

Comment: blank. code not work